# MobileFirst 8.0 using user credential in database for mobile client login?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

I know the users can be configured in server.xml like this way :

```
 <!-- The users defined here are members of group "appcentergroup", thus have role "appcenteradmin", and can therefore perform administrative tasks through the Application Center Console. -->
    <user name="appcenteradmin" password="admin"/>
    <user name="demo" password="demo"/>
    <group name="appcentergroup">
        <member name="appcenteradmin"/>
        <member name="demo"/>
    </group>
```

But if there is thoundsand of users, how to configure mobileFirst using the user credential in database to login mobile client (IBMAppcenter)?

Answer (score 0):

The default configuration added by IBM Application Center is to read a limited set of users from basic file based registry. The pre-defined roles are mapped to these users.

When you have thousands of users, it is most likely in a LDAP. In this scenario, you should configure your application server with this LDAP and have Application center validate the users against the LDAP. Role mappings are associated such that after the user validates successfully against the LDAP, it is assigned the appropriate role.

More details here:

1. [Configuring LDAP with Liberty](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_8.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/appcenter/t_ac_lib_ldap.html)
2. [Configuring LDAP ACL management](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_8.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/appcenter/r_ac_lib_ldap_acl.html)
3. [AppCenter LDAP JNDI parameters](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_8.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/appcenter/r_ac_jndi_property_list.html)